# Compare a date to a list of holidays

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In excel, I want to compare a date, lets say column A1, to a list of dates in a matrix, A2:F9 and report if its a "holiday". I have all the holidays in the matrix where the years are listed on the left row, and the holiday listed in the top column. The first group below are all the dates. I do have it going to 2050. The second group is the matrix where I only show some of the holidays. But I wannna compare, lets say the first date of "4/27/2018" in the first group, and under Holiday, annotate whether its in the second group below by putting "Yes" or "Holiday"

```
Date        day    month    year   Holiday 
4/27/2018   Fri    Apr      2018     ??
4/28/2018   Sat    Apr      2018     
4/29/2018   Sun    Apr      2018    
4/30/2018   Mon    Apr      2018    
5/1/2018    Tue    May      2018    


        New Years Day   Martin Luther King Jr.  Presidents Day
2018    1/1/2018        1/20/2018               2/19/2018
2019    1/1/2019        1/18/2019               2/18/2019
2020    1/1/2020        1/17/2020               2/17/2020
2021    1/1/2021        1/16/2021               2/15/2021
2022    1/1/2022        1/15/2022               2/21/2022
```

Comment: Let me know if this displays ok? I have excel 2007.

Comment: I only have 2007. I was unaware of the datefind function.

Answer (score 1):

> ... annotate whether its in the second group below by putting "Yes" or "Holiday"

It seems you simply want to know whether the day is a holiday or not.

The following formula should work in your sample data:

```
{=IF(OR(A2=$B$10:$D$14),"Yes", "No")}
```

It is a array formula. Don't put the second bracket manually, rather press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER together and the bracket will appear automatically.

Please see the formula in formula bar in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Very clever.  You can actually make it even simpler: just `{=OR(A2=$B$10:$D$14)}`.  The results will be TRUE or FALSE.  +1

Comment: HammeringOracle wanted to see "Yes" or "Holiday". That's why I used IF function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate to return the correct column number to an INDEX:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$1:$L$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($J$2:$L$6)-MIN(COLUMN($J$2:$L$6))+1)/($J$2:$L$6=A2),1)),"")
```

[image]

---

If you only want a TRUE/FALSE return then this entered as an array will do it:

```
=OR(A2=$J$2:$L$6)
```

Being an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

It will return TRUE if any of the dates in the second list match the one being referenced.

[image]

Comment: I did get Or to work. Thanks for that but have problems with =IFERROR(INDEX($L$1:$Z$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($L$2:$Z$33)-MIN(COLUMN($L$2:$Z$33))+1)/($L$2:$Z$33=A2),1)),"")...I'm not familiar with aggregate. It seems to keep everything blank.

Comment: You may not have the AGGREGATE function it came out with 2010 and some 2007 Excels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses older functions that should work in Excel 2007 (I'm actually using LO Calc and it works there).

[image]
*Click on image for larger view*

You asked to just show Yes or Holiday.  This solution shows the actual holiday.  If you want just the generic reference, the formula would be a little simpler.

The formula in E2 (copied down the column) is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$1:$J$1,1,MATCH(A2,INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,1)+1&":J"&MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,1)+1),0)),"")
```

I'll explain it from the inside out.

```
MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,1)
```

This finds the row for the year in the Holidays matrix.  The row is relative to the range of the matrix, with data starting in row 2, so we need to add 1 to that for the actual row in the worksheet.

```
INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,1)+1&":J"&MATCH(D2,$G$2:$G$6,1)+1)
```

The INDIRECT function builds a reference to the range in which you look for the date.  For 2018, this produces a range of H2:J2 (adjust the formula for your actual range).  For readability, I'll refer to the formula above as just INDIRECT() in the explanation below.

```
MATCH(A2,INDIRECT(),0)
```

Match then finds the column in that range where the date in A2 is located.  It produces an error if the date is not found (i.e., not a holiday).

If you want just a generic result, you can stop there and just wrap that in an IF test to check for an error condition (error = no holiday, a non-error result = holiday), and display the wording of your choice for either result.

```
INDEX($H$1:$J$1,1,MATCH(A2,INDIRECT(),0))
```

This looks up the identified column in the top row containing the holiday names.  I'll refer to this as just INDEX() for readability in the explanation below.

```
IFERROR(INDEX(),"")
```

This wraps the result in the IFERROR function to blank out the error message if it is not a holiday.